# concurrent execution of multiple java agents

Tags: java, javaagents

We have 3 agents Agent B has to start when Agent A has stopped. Agent C has to monitor whether Agent A and Agent B are in running state or not. How can this communication happen

Comment: Please describe your purpose more clearly.

Comment: Your description is too general, but as fas as I understand you want 3 threads. You submit the A to a Task and the C to another. The C can include an implementation to watch the A thread and based on a threshold to start thread B. Is that something that fits to the solution you are looking?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add all javaagents like this:
java -javaagent:A.jar -javaagent:B.jar -javaagent:C.jar MyJavaProgram